# How to run python from usb?

Tags: python

I am trying to download and run Python and PyCharm off of a usb stick because I am a newbie and suck with remembering all the OS specific setup, so the code I work on at work, does not work on my home computer.

When I try to run python.exe from the usb drive, I get the error "Windows cannot access the specified device path or file you may not have appropriate permissions". I am local admin and can open folders, just not run the exe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

TL;DR I want a centralized place for all of my code to be neatly and easily stored, retrieved, edited, and tested.

Comment: "usb or harddisk" it's not a good place for storing your work you need to learn git & github & how it's so good & powerful , specially for your sensitive work or projects

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. It just seems so daunting to me. The website...the desktop app...branches...settings files, prereq files...but I guess I'll never learn if I never try.

Comment: working in different environments , let you face a lot of errors & wrong stuff that let you upgrade your skills & knowledge

Comment: you don't really "run" python.exe directly by clicking on the ".exe".  You need to pass a script to it, so it may be more something like `d:\python.exe d:\path\to\some\script.py` from a command line.  But it would also be surprising if python is not already installed on your system.  You also don't necessarily need the python.exe on your usb disk to run the .py files that are stored on it if you have python installed at the system level (and your python versions match). Try running the .py files, not python.exe.

Comment: I basically just wanted a portable "environment" so I didn't have to add python and "dependencies"(I'm not sure the exact word I am looking for) to every computer I wanted  to work on.

Answer (score 1):

use python virtualenv

```
pip install virtualenv
python -m virtualenv mypython
```

It will generate a 'new' python (`mypython`) that you may copy into your USB stick.

Read the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Portable Python](https://portablepython.com).

Python virtualenv use your installed python that's why you can't share it using usb stick or add it on your github repository.